# 'FriendshipRequest' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a page that displays all the friend requests for a user. Everything seems to work until I get to the line where I render the page.

I am using Django.

**View**

```
def friend_requests(request):

    current_user = request.user.username
    user_id = (User.objects.get(username=current_user)).id
    all_requests = FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(to_user_id=user_id)
    friend_requests = []

    for request in all_requests:
        from_user_id = request.from_user_id
        from_user_id_username =(User.objects.get(pk=from_user_id)).username
        friend_requests.append(from_user_id_username)

    # for some reason i'm getting an attribute error here
    return render(request, 'Users/friend_requests.html', {'friend_requests': friend_requests})
```

**Template (friend_requests.html)**

```
{% for request in friend_requests %}

{{request}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what's the error you get? And.. why are you retrieving the user_id from the DB?

Comment: I added the error the original post. There is a separate database for friend requests. I am retrieving all the requests where the user_id matches the to_user_id. (A friend request row in the database has an ID, from_user_id, and to_user_id.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable `request` you create when looping through `friend_requests` is shadowing the context processor `{{request}}` which represents the current request client has made.

Change your variable name sth different than `request` and you'll probably be good to go:

```
{% for friend_request in friend_requests %}

  {{friend_request}} object of the current user {{request.user}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This was exactly what it was. Thank you for your help.